# torch.Size object has no attribute 'as_list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I got an issue when I try to develop infer to give result. But unfortunately, it could be don. The following code will define infer and load the model saved before (*.h5 file):

```
def infer(text, tokenizer, max_len=120):
    device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    class_names =  ['thế giới', 'thể thao', 'văn hóa', 'vi tính']
    model = keras.models.load_model('./models/cnn_nlp_text_classification_4_classer.h5')

    encoded_review = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        text,
        max_length=max_len,
        truncation=True,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        padding='max_length',
        return_attention_mask=True,
        return_token_type_ids=False,
        return_tensors='pt',
    )

    input_ids = encoded_review['input_ids']
    # print(input_ids)
    attention_mask = encoded_review['attention_mask']
    # print(attention_mask)

    output = model(input_ids, attention_mask)
    output = torch.randn(1, 3)
    
    _, y_pred = torch.max(output)

    print(f'Text: {text}')
    print(f'Sentiment: {class_names[y_pred]}')
```

After define infer, I do call to process but it returns the failure as below:

```
from tensorflow import keras
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/phobert-base")
infer('Chào mừng mọi người đến với bản tin thể thao 360 tối nay !', tokenizer)
```

Output and error:

```
Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (3002 > 256). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
tensor([[    0, 29048, 36475,  ..., 36475,   381,     2]])
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-56984d69c6cb> in <module>
      2 from tensorflow import keras
      3 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("vinai/phobert-base")
----> 4 infer('Chào mừng mọi người đến với bản tin thể thao 360 tối nay !', tokenizer)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in display_shape(shape)
    269 
    270 def display_shape(shape):
--> 271   return str(tuple(shape.as_list()))
    272 
    273 

AttributeError: 'torch.Size' object has no attribute 'as_list'
```